# Excel macro for series autofill

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I would like to ask how to create macro to autofill serial/series(1, 2, 3 and so on) from row A2 up to the end of data where there is data from Column B?

I use this code:

```
  Sub FillHandle()
  If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then Exit Sub
  If ActiveCell.Row = Rows.Count Then Exit Sub
  If ActiveCell.Column > 1 Then
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(, -1)) And Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1)) Then
      Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(, -1).End(xlDown).Offset(, 1)).FillDown
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End If
  If ActiveCell.Column < Columns.Count Then
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(, 1)) And Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1)) Then
      Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(, -1)).FillDown
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

However, it just autofill "1" all through out.

Below is the format of my excel sheet.

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I find the solution and I'll it share it for others who needs it also:

```
Sub FillSerialNumbers()
  With Range("A2:A" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = 1
    .DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1, Trend:=False
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Range.AutoFill method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx) is not the same as the [Range.DataSeries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839262.aspx).

```
Sub FillHandle()
    Dim lr As Long

    'do not know what this is for
    If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then Exit Sub
    'do not know what this is for either
    If ActiveCell.Row = Rows.Count Then Exit Sub

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")   '<~~ you should always know what worksheet you are on
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(2, "A") = 1
        .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(lr, "A")).DataSeries _
            Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1
    End With

    'if the series is to be linear but not 1, 2, 3, etc then supply both
    ' the first and last value and let .Series fill in the difference
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")   '<~~ you should always know what worksheet you are on
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(2, "A") = 1
        .Cells(lr, "A") = 99
        .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(lr, "A")).DataSeries _
            Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, _
            Step:=(.Cells(lr, "A").Value2 - .Cells(2, "A").Value2) / (lr - 2)
    End With


End Sub
```

The first example is a strictly *1, 2, 3* ordinal. The latter is a relative series fill where the first and last value and known but not necessarily the number of rows rows in between.